# Spring data jpa query to return with multiple properties

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have to fetch Users by id and state.The method takes a set of usersIds as input.
I need a jpa query like below:
`public Set<Users> fetchUsersByIdsContainingStateId(Set<Integer> userIds, Integer stateId)`
Is there a query like the above in Spring Data JPA or I need to resort to named query

Comment: Except for very simple cases, it's always a good idea to use the Query annotation, and to choose the best name you can imagine for the method. Just write the JPQL, it's simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use spring data query:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
   Set<User> findUserByIdInAndStageId(Set<Long> userIds , Long stageId);

   @Query("select u from User u where u.id in (:userIds) and u.stage.id=:stageId")
   Set<User> findUserByUserIdsAndStageId(@Param("userIds") Set<Long> userIds , @Param("stageId") Long stageId);

}
```

> for method findUserByIdInAndStageId spring data generates something
> like
>
> --         whereuser0_.id in (? , ? , ?...)) and stage1_.id=?

method findUserByUserIdsAndStageId do the same as findUserByIdInAndStageId , but in Query annotation you should write your query.

second search method findUserByUserIdsAndStageId named just for example , but I'll change it into something more readable like findUserWithStage(......)

PC don't use for domain model plural name like Users , use singular User